# InvalidOperationException error being recicved when testing .net core 2.2 web api controller

Tags: c#

I am creating a .Net web api using C# for .Net 2.2.  I am implementing the repository design pattern and I have been following this tutorial: https://www.forevolve.com/en/articles/2017/10/02/design-patterns-web-api-service-and-repository-part-11/

my code builds and runs successfully until I test with postman to send a request to my api controller, the error that I am getting is:

> System.InvalidOperationException: No constructor for type 'Cotal.Infrastructure.Repositories.TableStorageRepository`1[Cotal.Models.EventEntity]' can be instantiated using services from the service container and default values.

My startup.cs file has the following:

`services.TryAddSingleton<ITableStorageRepository<EventEntity>, TableStorageRepository<EventEntity>>();`

and my EventEntity Model looks like this:

```
  public class EventEntity : TableEntity
    {
        public EventEntity()
        {

        }
        
        public EventEntity(string userId, string rowKey)
        {
            PartitionKey = userId;
            RowKey = rowKey;
        }

        public int BrandId { get; set; }
```

The concrete class for TableStorageRepository looks like this (I have cut the rest of the code out for simplicity sake):

```
    public class TableStorageRepository<TModel> : StorageRepository<ITableStorageSettings>, ITableStorageRepository<TModel>
        where TModel : class, ITableEntity, new()
    {


        public TableStorageRepository(ITableStorageSettings storageSettings)
            : base(storageSettings)
        {
        }

        public TableStorageRepository(CloudTable table)
            : this(new CloudTableSettings(table))
        {

        }
```

Comment: Not relevant to your question, but i would strongly discourage creating a new API using .NET Core 2.2. It has been out-of-support for nearly a year and no longer receives bug fixes or security updates, leaving it vulnerable to various security issues. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-2-2-will-reach-end-of-life-on-december-23-2019/

Comment: More details on supported versions here: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core

Comment: thank you @Martin Costello :),  but non the less I am interested in trying to resolve this error.